# <style> tag not working within a vue.js element

Tags: css, vuejs2

Example:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Bob'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  Hello {{name}}
  <style>
  body { color: blue; }
  </style>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7g1vp68b/6/

When  tag is outside of the vue element, it renders okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vue can't parse `<style>` inside template.

If you check console log, there is an warning:

> Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI.
> Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as
>
> , as they will not be parsed.

You should place `<style></style>` outside of Vue template, or using [Vue single file component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)